# Facebook's Get Url Like count API has limit?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I use graph API to get like count of specified URL:

**https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=[URL]**

This API can works on test environment, but we I deploy it to production environment, this API returns error: **No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.**

Is the API has any request limits?
Or, how can I resolve this issue?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: try to load with curl the url, maybe your software fails to use the network

Comment: also, I'm using it without https, only http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not an error message from Facebook's side, which would have had a more specific error code and/or description.

Looks like your production environment is misconfigured or has a firewall in place and you can't actually reach the API endpoints